# software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.s3exception: null with using GetObjectRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use this code but i'm getting an exeption

```
var awsBasicCredentials  =  Packages.software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials.create("ackey","secretkey");
var credentials =  Packages.software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsBasicCredentials);

var region = Packages.software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region.AWS_CN_GLOBAL;
var uri =  Packages.java.net.URI.create("http://host");
var client =  Packages.software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client.builder()
                                                            
                                                            .credentialsProvider(credentials)
                                                            .region(region)
                                                            .endpointOverride(uri)
                                                            .build(); 
var request  = Packages.software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest.builder()
                                                                        .bucket("/bucketname")                                      
                                                                        .key("key")
                                                                        .build();
var response = client.getObject(request);
return response;
```

I am using /bucketname because the final link looks like host/bucketname instead bucketname.host

S3Exeption:

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: tx0000000000000162eece0-00633fea7f-306fc-msk-rt1)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:125)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handleResponse(CombinedResponseHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.CombinedResponseHandler.handle(CombinedResponseHandler.java:60)
```

Comment: Why are you overriding the endpoint with `http://host`?

Comment: Because I am not using a config file

Comment: The `endpoint` tells the AWS SDK where to find the AWS service. Typically, there should be no need to modify this field unless you are using an S3-compatible service hosted elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Bucket names can consist only of lowercase letters, numbers, dots (.), and hyphens (-).

Here is S3 Java code that works and returns a byte[] that represents the object that is located in the given **Amazon S3 bucket**.

In this example, the path represents the local file system where the object is written to . FOr example, a PDF file.

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class GetObjectData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     final String usage = "\n" +
         "Usage:\n" +
         "    <bucketName> <keyName> <path>\n\n" +
         "Where:\n" +
         "    bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket name. \n\n"+
         "    keyName - The key name. \n\n"+
         "    path - The path where the file is written to. \n\n";

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String keyName = args[1];
        String path = args[2];

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        getObjectBytes(s3,bucketName,keyName, path);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.main]
    public static void getObjectBytes (S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName, String path) {

        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

            // Write the data to a local file.
            File myFile = new File(path );
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            os.write(data);
            System.out.println("Successfully obtained bytes from an S3 object");
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.getobjectdata.main]
}
```

Comment: with this issue the endpoint will be like bucketName.host but i need to use host/bucketName, this is due to the peculiarities of the server settings